# Powerpoint / Word metafile (vectorized image) to pdf losing transparency

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, microsoft-powerpoint, vector-graphics

Is there a way I can keep the image vectored without losing its transparency? I know I can just save the image (or paste) as .PNG, but I want to keep it as a vector image.

Original power point image

[image: Original power point image]

Saved as .PDF image, vector image but no transparency
[image: Saved as .PDF image, vector image but no transparency]

Print as pdf:

[image: Print as pdf]

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a Microsoft Office Drawing Object? Right click on your EMF vector and select "Ungroup". You'll be asked to convert it to a Microsoft Office Drawing Object. Click "Yes", and then try saving as PDF. You can keep "ungrouping" to separate your image into individual layers if you need to, so you can move layers around.

Comment: The same happens for Microsoft Office Drawing Object

Comment: Added a print as pdf version. A bit better but still stinks

Comment: How many graphics are you working with? If it's just a few, then you could convert the vectors to images, save as PDF, and not save the changes in your PowerPoint? I'm looking into some "fancier" options, but if you don't have a ton of images this might be a work around.

Comment: I don't want to save as image, I'll loose the vectors. This is the purpose of this topic. I just found that if I remove the PDF/A Compliant the image is saved as vector and perfect quality.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, feel free to post it as an answer. That way, others looking for a similar solution will see an answered question. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out why, from [wiki PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A):

> Transparent objects and layers (Optional Content Groups) are forbidden
>   in PDF/A-1, but are allowed in PDF/A-2.

For some stupid Stone Age reason PDF/A-1 does NOT support transparency and layers. There is no PDF/A-2 option in word so... I'm saving now as non compliant to PDF/A.